# Why use quote and dot before $_POST in insert query?

Tags: php

For example I have a html file like below:

```
<html>
  <form action="insert.php" method="post">
    Name:<input type="text" name="txtname" />
    <input type="submit" name="but" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</html>
```

and a php file like below:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['but']))
  {
    mysqli_query($con,"insert into student(Name) values(".$_POST["txtname"].")");
  }
?>
```

My question is that if I can write `$name=$post['txtname']` and I use `$name` in values part then dot
is not used but if I write directly post in values part then dot is used, why this dot used?

Comment: Otherwise the double quote for the index of `$_POST` would stop the string!

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections; you should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: save the query in a variable and echo it. And execute the echo string in phpmyadmin will give you the result of whether the written query is right or wrong?

Comment: May be the column `Name` can be a data type of varchar

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilitys to do this...

First:

```
mysqli_query($con,"insert into student(Name) values(" . $_POST['txtname'] . ")");
// using single quotes instead of double quotes
```

Second

```
mysqli_query($con,"insert into student(Name) values({$_POST['txtname']})");
//dont use any dots but single quotes and simply add it to the string
```

Also you should care about some singlequotes to the content...

```
"... values('{$_POST['txtname']}')"
```

so it should be

```
mysqli_query($con,"insert into student(Name) values('{$_POST['txtname']}')");
```

and as in the comments pointed... you have injection problems and consider to solve this.

Your PHP

```
<?php 
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'foobar');

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO students ( Name ) VALUES ( ? )");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['txtname']);

    /* execute prepared statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

    /* close statement and connection */
    $stmt->close();

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$name` with and without dots, but $_POST['something'] is different in the way that the index has quotes. It will break your query.

It is not related to `$_POST` it is related to `arrays`

You could also write it like

```
mysqli_query($con,"insert into student(Name) values('{$_POST['txtname']}')");
```

On another note, you should not insert form input directly into the database.
Do some validation first.

Comment: This will cause an error because you stopping the string when you use the POST like this. String is: `"insert into student(Name) values('{$_POST["` and than you will get the error...

Comment: Actually the information between the curly brackets is handled by PHP so it shouldn't affect the query but I'll change it.